# In what order are functions executed in Processing?

Tags: function, processing

My code does exactly what I want it to do, but I don't understand why. I get that `setup()` is called once when the sketch starts, but I'm not really sure about `draw()` and `mouseMoved()`. I think that `draw()` is called right after `setup()` and executed over and over again, but if that's the case, where does `mouseMoved()` come in? I never even called it, but it still gets executed. If `draw()` is getting executed continuously, how can `mouseMoved()` be executed at all? Are they executed at the same time?

```
float radius = 50.0;
int x, y;
int mx, my;
int delay = 16;

void setup()
{
  size(200, 200);
  strokeWeight(10);
  frameRate(15);
  x = width / 2;
  y = height / 2;
}

void draw()
{
  radius += sin(frameCount / 4);

  x += (mx-x)/delay;
  y += (my-y)/delay;

  background(100);

  fill(0, 121, 184);

  stroke(255);

  ellipse(x, y, radius, radius);

}

void mouseMoved()
{
  mx = mouseX;
  my = mouseY;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you said, `setup()` is called once once the program starts. It *sets* everything up. Then `draw()` is called, by default, 60 times a second. According to the [documentation](http://processing.org/reference/draw_.html):

> Called directly after setup(), the draw() function continuously
>   executes the lines of code contained inside its block until the
>   program is stopped or noLoop() is called. draw() is called
>   automatically and should never be called explicitly.

And events such as `mousePressed()` and `mouseMoved()` etc. are continuously called within the `draw()` function automatically.

> There can only be one draw() function for each sketch, and draw() must
>   exist if you want the code to run continuously, or to process events
>   such as mousePressed().

Now, `mouseMoved()` does the following (link [here](http://www.processing.org/reference/mouseMoved_.html)):

> The mouseMoved() function is called every time the mouse moves and a
>   mouse button is not pressed. (If a button is being pressed,
>   mouseDragged() is called instead.)

`draw()` is what keeps listening for events to see if the mouse moved or not. And if the mouse moves, then that event is sent to `mouseMoved()` and it does what is defined within it.

If you want to test how certain functions are called, place a `noLoop()` in `draw()` and then you'll see that `mouseMoved()` does not get called. You can also change the amount of times `draw()` gets called in a second by using `frameRate()` (see [here](http://www.processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html)).

Comment: The default FPS is 60, not 30. More info here: http://processing.org/reference/frameRate_.html